# Question about the general case of $\sqrt{ab} \leq(a + b) / 2$

Tags: calculus

I'm an amateur working through Spivak's *Calculus* and one of the early exercises is:

given that $0 \le a \le b$, prove that a $ \sqrt{ab} \le \frac{a+b}{2}$

I eventually managed to barely puzzle through a proof for this that someone had posted on here. After playing around a bit, I've come to suspect that this could be generalized to imply that the $n$th root of $n$ numbers is less than or equal to the mean of the sum of those numbers. My understanding of the special case is admittedly shallow so I really don't know where to start with proving or disproving the following "conjecture":

Given that $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3,\ldots x_n \in \mathbb R^+,$

$$\sqrt[n]{\strut x_1x_2x_3\cdots x_n} \le \frac{x_1+ x_2+ x_3+\cdots+x_n}{n}$$

My question is, am I correct? If so, why? Does this idea have a name?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Did you mean `⋅` where you typed `,` in the left side of the inequality and `+` where you typed `,` on the right?  Cf. [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#The_inequality).

Comment: Yes, this conjecture is true, assuming some edits. It is called the AM/GM inequality because one value is the arithmetic mean  and the other the geometric mean. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means

Comment: The general proof for $n$ numbers is actually a chapter 2 problem in Spivak. Very cool you were able to anticipate the generalization.

Comment: You don't need $a\le b$, $0\le a,b$ is enough.

Answer (score 1):

**By induction:**

Let us assume that $g$ and $a$ are the geometric and arithmetic mean of $n-1$ numbers. Then I claim that for any non-negative number $x$

$$g\le a\implies\sqrt[n]{g^{n-1}x}\le\frac{(n-1)a+x}n.$$

Indeed, this can be rewritten
$$\left(\frac gx\right)^{(n-1)/n}\le\frac{(n-1)\dfrac ax+1}n$$

and we can show the stronger

$$\left(\frac gx\right)^{(n-1)/n}\le\frac{(n-1)\dfrac gx+1}n$$

which derives from Bernouilli's inequality for $0<\alpha<1$:
$$t^\alpha\le\alpha(t-1)+1.$$